# Issue with onCreateView - Fragment

Tags: android, view

I have this simple piece of code in my program

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);


    return rootView;
}
```

When in put a breaker point in front of the View rootView = ... line the debugger gives me this.

[image: debugger]

Where does this loader variable comes from? This confuses me.

Here is my xml file.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
       <RelativeLayout
           android:padding="16dp"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/movie_title"

               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingTop="20dp"
               />
           <TextView
               android:layout_below="@+id/movie_title"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:id="@+id/movie_rating"
               android:text="9/10"
               android:textSize="24sp"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingTop="20dp"
               />
           <TextView
               android:layout_below="@+id/movie_rating"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:id="@+id/movie_date"
               android:text="2017-10-9"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingTop="20dp"
               />
       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have instant run on?

Comment: Are you sure the version you try to debug and the code are exactly the same?

Comment: @ Eselfar . Well I think so. How do I check that?

Comment: @poss Yes I do.

Comment: Could you show the whole code for fragment?

Comment: @kimkevin I have uploaded the project in github. Please go at MoviesFragment class. https://github.com/theo82/PopularMoviesPart2

Comment: iirc instant run uses loaders and extra fields for hot swap, but not sure if it's the case here. Easy test would be disabling instant run, restart studio (not necessary, but just to be sure), check for field again.